# Is Roo based on Soros?

Tags: raymond-e-feist, riftwar-cycle, serpentwar-saga

The career of Roo in [Rise of a Merchant Prince](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rise_of_a_Merchant_Prince) is eerily reminiscent of the life and career of [George Soros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Soros). Is the similarity accidental, or intentional?

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, wasn't Roo really a facsimile of James, who rose under Arutha to become a Squire after a boyhood of being a thief in the original Riftwar series?

I am not saying that Feist would not base the character on a person IRL, it just seemed to me like he created an initial set of archetypes and then reused them in each of his successive books under different names.

Therefore my guess is that any similarity is accidental.